# Facebook image order

Tags: ios, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller

I was trying to use the post to facebook using an UIActivityViewController. I did set the data array and everything works fine but there is a issue with the image order. The images I post to facebook does not preserve the order of the image array I gave to the UIActivityViewController. The posting order seems to be random. Is there any way to post these pictures to facebook with the given order.

Appreciate your help.

code i use:`UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:_imagesToShare
     applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];`

```
_imagesToShare is the array with the image and caption objects.
```